# Different files (pdf, doc, xls) generated by jasperreports 6.0.3 have different fonts

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf, export-to-word

I am using a .jasper file to generate documents (pdf, doc, xls).
Here is the sample jrxml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d5daadb7-9081-40d7-b44e-80caa3d27ae5">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
  <queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
  </queryString>
  <title>
    <band height="110" splitType="Stretch">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="105" y="64" width="344" height="30" uuid="f8bef38d-aff5-49c0-a499-4d003c3f4330"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[HELLO WORLD]]></text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </title>
  <detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
  </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

When the files are generated, the pdf file has font Arial, doc file has Times New Roman, and the excel file has the font SansSerif.

How can I get all doc types to have Arial font?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, jasperreports-6.0.3.

Comment: Have you tried exporting report using font extension ?  Please see [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

Comment: You did not set font for the text. 1) You should use font extensions 2) You can use style with properties for defining font to use

Comment: Hi @FahadAnjum , I followed the link. I was able to generate docs with Arial font when previewing from jaspersoft studio. But I am unable to generate such files from outside the studio (i.e. only using the jasperreports library, I tried adding Arial.jar to the library directory).

Comment: Have you tried adding Arial.jar as external library ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum Yes, I tried that.
I'm trying to do something similar to this [link](https://johnwilfred.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-fonts-to-jasper-based-pdf-reports/)

Comment: The link provided by @FahadAnjum did the job. I made a silly mistake of not updating the library path of my jars after making a copy of my project.